# Scroll to Top on Home Button Press

Tags: react-native

On my React Native project, I have current have two Tab Screens: a home page and a profile page. The home page is just a flatlist. How do I make it so if the user is on the home page, and they click on the home page icon again, the flatlist scrolls to the top?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Scroll to top with React Navigation.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).